# Using PHP's mail() - name.com hosting issue

Tags: php, html, email

my site is hosted on name.com, and to test this I uploaded a simple file called contact.php with this at the top.

```
<?php

$to = '~~~~';
$subject = 'enquiry from ';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email - $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if ($_POST){
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
$feedback = "Sent";
}
?>
```

So, when I click the submit button it sends the mail. Inside a p tag I have echo $feedback, which shows up after I click submit.

The mail does not send? Anything I'm doing wrong here, or do I need to configure my cPanel in some way?

Comment: you have a typo on `line 6`. It should be an `=` sign and not `-`.

Comment: I still think you should add a header, like I posted in my answer. Anyway, did you get it working?

Comment: @Sergio Ya, I changed it up as suggested - It works on XAMPP local server, but when I use it on my site it doesnt send to the email set in the $to parameter, but instead to the Home directory -> Mail -> New inside the cPanel file manager. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @BrettD it's also going there for me. How to fix?

Comment: @AdamMoisa : name.com is a shared host. You need sudo/kernel permissions to use core libraries like on localhost. Contact them to solve this permission issue or buy a VPS and set up your own servers. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Since header is optional and is left undefined, removing it should resolve your issue.

Comment: I made the variable $feedback = mail(...), which is echoed upon clicking submit. It returns 1, yet I am still not receiving the email.

Comment: Not from what I can see, you set `$feedback = 'Sent';` which will fire as long as `$_POST` is set not because the mail is sent.

Comment: Mail returns a boolean, so by setting $feedback = mail(), eachoing $feedback should = 1 if it is sent. I'm getting 1, but it's not coming to my inbox.

Comment: I dont see `$feedback` set to anything other than Sent.

Comment: $feedback = "Sent"; you will get **sent** when echoed `$feedback`. Wondering how you will get 1.

Comment: The code works in XAMPP, but not on my server. However it I head to my home directory, and into Mail -> New, the emails are in there.. but not my gmail inbox specified by $to

Answer (score 0):

You have not set header variable which is optional, there is a typo while setting $email variable, you've use - instead of =

your updated code,

```
<?php
    $to = 'a@a.com';
    $subject = 'enquiry from ';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if ($_POST){
        mail($to, $subject, $message);
        $feedback = "Sent";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Even with these edits it will not send. Do I need some editing in the php configuration to send mail?

Comment: @BrettD Did you checked your spam/junk folder?

Comment: @BrettD Then it might be your hosting issue, checkout with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that using the `$_POST` content directly into a email is a security risk for you!
THere are good email libraries that have tools to avoid abuses. (For example: [ZendMail](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.html&ei=UcINUv6EHsSC4AT9u4CICA&usg=AFQjCNGFJB6uWwBt24oEG-NmEeKPBsdk5w&sig2=g3ysgu6VmA8bs5nFb2W2Ew&bvm=bv.50768961,d.bGE), [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/))

Having said that, on your code you are missing the header and have a small mistake on `$email` `=` (not `-`) `$_POST['email'];`, you can use this:

```
$header = 'From: from@name.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: from@name.com' . "\r\n" .
'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```